# PHP preg_replace does not replace normal string with multiple lines

Tags: php, xml, regex

I'm having a really weird problem with preg_replace here (and as far as I can remember, this isn't the first time I've seen this).
I have an XML with an element with invalid structure (closing tag is missing the slash, breaks parser):

```
<info> 
<datetime>2013.04.12 12:04:02</datetime> 
<info>
```

What I'm trying to do is this: `$xml = preg_replace('/<info>.*<info>/iu', '', $xml)` (because I don't actually need that element), but IT DOES NOT REPLACE.
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `s` modifier and use `?` to make it non-greedy:

```
$string = '<info> 
<datetime>2013.04.12 12:04:02</datetime> 
<info>
<valid>2013.04.12 12:04:02</valid>
<info> 
<datetime>2013.04.12 12:04:02</datetime> 
<info>';
var_dump(preg_replace('/<info>.*?<info>/s', '', $string));
```

Comment: Ok, adding the ? worked. Thanks! Might I ask why did it work?

Comment: @jurchiks so first you are commenting that do not read your question entirely... and now you are asking why it worked **even though it is already explained in the answer?** `.*?` is a way to make the match non-greedy.

Comment: It isn't EXPLAINED in the answer, it just says "make it non-greedy". That doesn't mean anything to me, I'm not a regex guru. Check Álvaro G. Vicario's answer for an example of a very good explanatory answer. Sure, I got the fix I was looking for, but a good explanation on why it works would be good not just for me but for everyone else reading the replies later on.

Comment: @jurchiks You edited your comment waaaaaaaa ! Well Álvaro G. Vicario just explained what the s modifier does, which I think isn't even needed since it's all documented in the PHP docs, and honestly there are several articles on the net about **greedy vs non-greedy**.

Comment: `.*` would match anything. `.*a` *should* match everything that ends with an `a`. However, because `.*` is greedy, it will match that `a` too, which leaves no more `a`'s to match at the end, making it fail. By making it non-greedy, this is prevented.

Comment: In your case, `.*` would match `<info>` too. The last part of your regular expression is trying to find an ending `<info>`, but it's already consumed by our greedy villain `.*`.

Comment: @HamZa - I *added* to my comment, didn't edit the existing text. A thorough explanation right in the answer is much better than sending the person around to "google it" or "read this wall of text over here". @ Tim - thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @jurchiks I agree with you, thanks anyways for the reps :)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't replace becase there aren't matches:

```
<?php

$xml = '<info>
    <datetime>2013.04.12 12:04:02</datetime>
<info>';
var_dump(preg_match('/<info>.*<info>/iu', $xml, $matches), $matches);
```

```
int(0)
array(0) {
}
```

Let's see what's wrong. [What does `.` mean exactly](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php)?

> match any character except newline (by default)

So there it is! How do you change the default? We have a look at the available [internal options](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php) and find this:

> `s` for `PCRE_DOTALL`

.... where [PCRE_DOTALL means](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>       If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are
>   excluded.

We can change it locally:

```
'/<info>(?s:.*)<info>/iu'
          ^
```

... or globally:

```
'/<info>.*<info>/ius'
                   ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `s` modifier to the regex rule. Will not stop matching at new line

Comment: Does not work, returns an empty string... err, it returns `null`

Comment: @jurchiks check the source code :p

Comment: what source code? `var_dump(preg_replace('/<info>.*<info>/ius', '', $response));` => null

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

You need to use the s modifier at the end of your regex.

```
$xml = preg_replace('/<info>.*<info>/ius', '', $xml);
```